# Web deploy and folder permissions

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-deployment-project, msdeploy

I'm using VS 2010 to build the deployment package for a web application. I manually deploy it to the IIS 6.0 server using the deployment ccommand script it generates. All the stuff gets copied under the Inetpub default website properly. The only issue I have is that the folder permissions keep getting reset once I deploy.

Say my website is under the folder "Mywebsite". I grant certain user XYS full control to this folder. All is well. The next time I deploy, user XYZ no longer has full control and the permissions gets reset.

Comment: Isn't this a question for Superuser.com?

Comment: Can't you set this specific permission in your deployment? http://sedodream.com/2011/11/08/SettingFolderPermissionsOnWebPublish.aspx

Answer (score 9):

If you want to skip ACL operations then you need to set a property in your build. You can do this in two ways

1. Edit your project file
2. Create a .wpp.targets file

I would recommend #2. For this case create a new file in the same directory as your project file with the name {ProjectName}.wpp.targets where {ProjectName} is the name of your project. Then inside of this file you should place the following contents.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
         ToolsVersion="4.0">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeSetAclProviderOnDestination>False</IncludeSetAclProviderOnDestination>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Here you are setting the property `IncludeSetAclProviderOnDestination` which will signal the Web Publishing Pipeline to not include ACL providers in the manifest that is created for the package/publish.

If you want to take approach #1 just throw in the entire  under the  elment.